# Highchart: how to add commas to output to intergers

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I Have the following code which generates a basic area chart from JSON data, on the chart i want to be able to show comma separated numbers instead of a whole integer ie all the number in the chart should show with a comma as **483,533,30** instead of just 48353330.

I added this bit as suggested in various examples but doesn't seem to be working

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang: {
                    thousandsSep: ','
                }
            });
```

My working code can be seen here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/hg1r1mkb/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang: {
                        thousandsSep: ','
                    }
                });

var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'area',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Deposit Institution',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': $'+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

                     $.getJSON("data1.json", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
      this.x + ': $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, '', ',');
  }
}
```

Try adding Highcharts.numberFormat to your tooltip formatter function
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat

Answer (score 0):

Try this with X or with Y:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter:function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried what that does it put commas pn the y axis , I doesnt put the commas in the chart itself